# log4j best practices for logging within an internal library (double logging)

Tags: logging, spring-mvc, log4j

Here is my setup:

- WEBAPP: Spring MVC web application
- LIBRARY: internal library I use
  within WEBAPP

In WEBAPP, I have an exception handler defined in my "base" controller as follows:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public final ModelAndView handleException(
        final Exception e,
        final HttpServletRequest request)
{
    // some stuff...
    LOG.error(message, e);
    // some more stuff...
}
```

where LOG is my log4j logger defined statically in the class.

Within LIBRARY, I log any exceptions as an error then rethrow them to the client.  In this case, the client is WEBAPP.  Now, as you can see, every time an error occurs, I have 2 log entries!  One for LIBRARY and one for WEBAPP.

I do not want to remove the exception handler for WEBAPP since exceptions can be thrown outside of LIBRARY and I want to log them before returning a 500 to the WEBAPP client.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take the approach that you should only catch an exception if you plan on doing something about it at that spot.  Logging the exception is not doing anything.  My recommendation is to not log in your library.  Simply let the exception bubble-up normally since it sounds like you are not trying to do anything special within your library.